# SAXParseException on file header with SUDS consuming SOAP service - how to consume soap properly?

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, soap, suds

Using a mac with Python 2.7.5 and suds==0.4

I am using suds (for the first time) to consume a soap web service using the wsdl. I am confused by the response when I request the XML raw as it fails to parse.

```
from suds.client import Client
from datetime import datetime

client = Client('http://domeintabellen-idsw-ws.rws.nl/DomainTableWS.svc?wsdl')
request = client.factory.create('ns1:GetDomainTableNamesRequest')
today = datetime.today()
request.CheckDate = today
result = client.service['basic'].GetDomainTableNames(request)
```

This gives me an error:

```
SAXParseException: <unknown>:2:43: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

I set the client to return the xml without parsing it to a python object:

```
client.set_options(retxml=True)
```

I get a return which I could manually parse. However I would like "it" to work properly and also understand better what the problem is.

The XML returned is as follows and seems to contain some headers. I noticed the +id in the uuid is being raised after each request.

```
--uuid:1d4b4778-364c-4743-8eb3-d72a1e3f7747+id=28
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetDomainTableNamesResponse xmlns="http://rws.services.nl/DomainTableWS/2010/10"><GetDomainTableNamesResult xmlns:a="http://rws.services.nl/DomainTableWS/Contracts/2010/10" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:DomainTableNames><a:string>Aanduiding_naamgebruik</a:string><a:string>Aanslag_type</a:string><a:string>Aanvoereenheid_soorten</a:string><a:string>Aanvoergebied_soorten</a:string><a:string>Aanwezig_afwezig_onbekend</a:string><a:string>Academische_titel</a:string><a:string>Adellijke_titel_of_predikaat</a:string><a:string>Afleveringspunt_soorten</a:string><a:string>Afsluitwijzen</a:string><a:string>Afvoergebied_soorten</a:string><a:string>Afwateringseenheid_soorten</a:string><a:string>AtRisktype</a:string><a:string>BBP_beheerproduct</a:string><a:string>BBP_beleidsproduct</a:string><a:string>Bedrijfstakken_WVOW</a:string><a:string>Beheersvormen_waterkering</a:string><a:string>Belastingsoorten</a:string><a:string>Bemalen_of_vrij_verval</a:string><a:string>Bemonsteringsapparaat</a:string><a:string>Bemonsteringsmethode</a:string><a:string>Bemonsteringssoort</a:string><a:string>Beoordeling_schade</a:string><a:string>BeschermdGebiedtype</a:string><a:string>Bestemmingen_afvalwater</a:string><a:string>Besturingswijze</a:string><a:string>Bevaarbaarheidsklassen</a:string><a:string>BevoegdGezagSoort</a:string><a:string>Beweegbare_bruggen</a:string><a:string>Biotaxon</a:string><a:string>Boomhoogte</a:string><a:string>Brander</a:string><a:string>CEFILT</a:string><a:string>ClassificatieCIW</a:string><a:string>ClassificatieKRWGW</a:string><a:string>ClassificatieKRWbiologischOW</a:string><a:string>ClassificatieKRWchemischOW</a:string><a:string>Code_stroomrichting</a:string><a:string>Code_sturing</a:string><a:string>Compartiment</a:string><a:string>Correspondentie_soorten</a:string><a:string>Detailonderdeel_bijzondere_weglaag</a:string><a:string>Detailplaats_lijnmarkering</a:string><a:string>DoelMeetLocatieType</a:string><a:string>Doelen_baggerwerkzaamheden</a:string><a:string>Doelen_voor_metingen</a:string><a:string>Doorspoelbaarheid</a:string><a:string>Drainerende_werking</a:string><a:string>Druk</a:string><a:string>Drukklassen</a:string><a:string>EBEOkarakteristiek</a:string><a:string>EUfonds</a:string><a:string>Ecologische_verbindingszone_soort</a:string><a:string>Eenheden_voor_precario</a:string><a:string>Eenheid</a:string><a:string>Effecttype</a:string><a:string>Eindbeeld_boomvakdeel</a:string><a:string>Eindbestemmingen_baggerspecie</a:string><a:string>EmissieBrontype</a:string><a:string>Energielevering_soorten</a:string><a:string>FunctieKunstwerk</a:string><a:string>Functies_van_adressen</a:string><a:string>Functies_vastgoedelementen_en_gebieden</a:string><a:string>Gebouwd_onbebouwd</a:string><a:string>Gebruikscodes_objecten</a:string><a:string>Geografische_schalen</a:string><a:string>Graderingen_filterlaag</a:string><a:string>Gras_beheervorm</a:string><a:string>Gras_soorten</a:string><a:string>Groenbeheerniveau</a:string><a:string>Groentype</a:string><a:string>Grondmechanische_aspect_soorten</a:string><a:string>Grondslagen</a:string><a:string>Grootheid_dummy</a:string><a:string>Heffingsobject_soorten</a:string><a:string>Hoedanigheid</a:string><a:string>IWSRindicator</a:string><a:string>Inrichtingtype</a:string><a:string>J_N_of_onbekend</a:string><a:string>J_of_N</a:string><a:string>KRWKwaliteitselement</a:string><a:string>KRWMaatregelGebiedsniveau</a:string><a:string>KRWMaatregeltype</a:string><a:string>KRWMeetLocatietype</a:string><a:string>KRWStatus</a:string><a:string>KRWStroomgebiedsdistrict</a:string><a:string>KRWWatertype</a:string><a:string>KRWhydromorfologische_parameter</a:string><a:string>Kabel_en_leiding_soorten</a:string><a:string>Koppelstuk_soorten</a:string><a:string>Kunstwerktype</a:string><a:string>Kwaliteitsoordeel</a:string><a:string>L_R_B</a:string><a:string>Leidingdeel_soorten</a:string><a:string>LocatietypeWaardeBepaling</a:string><a:string>Lozingsvoorziening_soorten</a:string><a:string>Materialen_voor_afvalwatertransportwerken</a:string><a:string>Materialen_voor_bekleding_waterkering_of_profiel</a:string><a:string>Materialen_voor_kunstwerken</a:string><a:string>Materialen_voor_leidingen</a:string><a:string>Materialen_voor_profielverdedigingen</a:string><a:string>Meetapparaat</a:string><a:string>Meetinstantie</a:string><a:string>Meting</a:string><a:string>Monsterbewerkingsmethode</a:string><a:string>Normgroep</a:string><a:string>Normkader</a:string><a:string>NoseCodetype</a:string><a:string>Onderzoekssoort</a:string><a:string>Onttrekkingsvoorziening_soorten</a:string><a:string>Onttrekkingtype</a:string><a:string>Opmerking_weglaag</a:string><a:string>OppervlakteCategorieStoomgebiedtype</a:string><a:string>Orgaan</a:string><a:string>Overige_vastgoedelement_soorten</a:string><a:string>Parameter</a:string><a:string>Plaatsbepalingsapparaat</a:string><a:string>Processen_RWZI</a:string><a:string>Processen_SVI</a:string><a:string>Processen_transportstelsel</a:string><a:string>Profiellijn_soorten</a:string><a:string>RWZI_soorten</a:string><a:string>Rechtsvormen_bedrijf</a:string><a:string>RedenGebruikLocatie</a:string><a:string>RichtlijnType</a:string><a:string>Rioleringselementen</a:string><a:string>Rioolstelsel_soorten</a:string><a:string>SGBPTitel</a:string><a:string>Scheepvaartteken</a:string><a:string>Soort_zorgplicht_voor_bomen</a:string><a:string>Staat</a:string><a:string>Stuw_soorten</a:string><a:string>Subject_rollen</a:string><a:string>Substraattype</a:string><a:string>TijdDimensietype</a:string><a:string>Tijdelijke_kroon</a:string><a:string>Vaarweg_soorten</a:string><a:string>Veer_typen</a:string><a:string>Verkeersvoorziening_boomvakdeel</a:string><a:string>Vormen</a:string><a:string>Waardebepalingsmethode</a:string><a:string>Waardebepalingstechniek</a:string><a:string>Waardebewerkingsmethode</a:string><a:string>Waarnemingssoort</a:string><a:string>WaterTypeKwantitatief</a:string><a:string>Waterbeheerder</a:string><a:string>Waterbeheergebiedtype</a:string><a:string>Waterkeringtype</a:string><a:string>Waterrijkheidtype</a:string><a:string>Waterstaatkundigezonering</a:string><a:string>WatertypeKwalitatief</a:string><a:string>WegAardtype</a:string><a:string>WetVerordeningtype</a:string><a:string>Zuivering_soorten</a:string><a:string>ZwemplekVoorzieningen</a:string></a:DomainTableNames></GetDomainTableNamesResult></GetDomainTableNamesResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>

--uuid:1d4b4778-364c-4743-8eb3-d72a1e3f7747+id=28--
```

I figured out this is the string returned and being parsed. In suds you can inject a message to test your responses:

```
response = \
"""<enter message here>""""

result = client.service['basic'].GetDomainTableNames(__inject={'reply':response})
```

So I threw in the XML string without the uuid and Content headers and it parsed just fine. However I tried to mess around with the uuid like removing the +id from it and it will not parse. Here is where I get lost. I do not think I have an encoding problem. I assume the parsing error is cause by the headers of the xml file.

I assume these headers are normal when I request the raw xml?

Does it fail on the + symbol in that uuid? And if so why?

How DO I get it parsed using suds? Or should I try another library?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried it with soapui, too. But could not find exactly the error. But a question, there are urls like 'xmlns="http://rws.services.nl/DomainTableWS/2010/10"'. I dont know if it is necessary but the host is unknown.

Comment: I actually also tried soapui this weekend but didn't update the question yet. There is not error with soapui. With pysimplesoap the error also occurs.

Answer (score 2):

When suds uses Urllib2 gets the HTTP headers an the data correctly

**Headers**

```
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "HTTP/1.0 200 OK[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 12:19:17 GMT[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Set-Cookie: BALANCEID=nwr-iavw-dnt1.node1;path=/;[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Mime-Version: 1.0[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Cache-Control: private[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:49c70d41-cde8-4e80-9834-23051887a718+id=6";start-info="text/xml"[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-Cache: MISS from ...[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ...:8128[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Via: 1.1 ...:8128 (squid/x.x.STABLE3)[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
```

**Data**

```
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "--uuid:49c70d41-cde8-4e80-9834-23051887a718+id=6[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetDomainTableNamesResponse xmlns="http://rws.services.nl/DomainTableWS/2010/10"><GetDomainTableNamesResult xmlns:a="http://rws.services.nl/DomainTableWS/Contracts/2010/10" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">...</GetDomainTableNamesResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
Wed Jan 29 13:19:15 CET 2014:DEBUG:<< "--uuid:49c70d41-cde8-4e80-9834-23051887a718+id=6--[\r][\n]"
```

Looks like the server returns a response data with the SOAP message and other things (--uuid... etc)

SOAPUI probably works because parse again the response data looking for the message only (or Apache HTTPClient handles the response as expected), but seems suds have a problem in the replyfilter (line 58) of the sud's [Binding](http://svn.fedorahosted.org/svn/suds/trunk/suds/bindings/binding.py) class, suds interprets that the valid response is all the data returned from Urllib2 and does not parse the message again.

```
    replyfilter = (lambda s,r: r)

...

    reply = self.replyfilter(reply)
```

suds 0.4 implements a plugin facility, so you can use the [MessagePlugin](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#MessagePlugin) to parse the data again an get the message only, a quick example

```
import logging
from suds.client import Client
from datetime import datetime
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class Filter(MessagePlugin):
    def received(self, context):
        reply = context.reply
        context.reply = reply[reply.find("<s:Envelope"):reply.rfind(">")+1]

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = Client('http://domeintabellen-idsw-ws.rws.nl/DomainTableWS.svc?wsdl', plugins=[Filter()])
request = client.factory.create('ns1:GetDomainTableNamesRequest')
today = datetime.today()
request.CheckDate = today
result = client.service['basic'].GetDomainTableNames(request)
```

I am not a python expert, you can use regular expressions too in an easy way to get the message and overwrite the `context.reply` content.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer. I did not have time yet to try out this myself but will do so this weekend.